# Can File Manager columns be added/edited?

Tags: pantheon-files

Can I add more columns to the ones I see?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

I searched gsettings for list, and it does have a couple of options, but none for the top bar:

[image]

So I wondered if it was somewhere else, so I searched for the names of the

collunms, specificlally `name` and `size`. This gave the following:

```
org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-visible-columns ['name', 'size', 'type', 'date_modified']
org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-column-order ['name', 'size', 'type', 'date_modified']
```

So that shows that only nautilus allows customisation. If you need different information, you could consider installing nautilus.